# Using Excel's find and searching by 2 strings

Tags: excel, vba

I need your help,

Is it possible to search an Excel spreadsheet based on 2 given values, as opposed to just 1? similar to that of an "AND" operator?

Here's what I have so far, but I guess if your looking for a needle in a hay stack:

```
Str = "apples" AND "oranges"

With Sheets(xSheet)

    Set foundCell = .Cells.Find(What:=Str, After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
End With
```

Comment: First create a range of ALL cells that contain *"apples"*.  Second create a range of ALL cells that contain *"oranges"*. Third use `Intersect()` on these ranges.

Comment: That would be complete calculus talk to me. Sorry I am new the VBA scene.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below returns the wanted result:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim str As String: str = "apples*oranges"
    Dim foundCell As Range

    Dim options As Variant
    options = Array(str, Split(str, "*")(1) & "*" & Split(str, "*")(0))
    Dim myVar As Variant

    For Each myVar In options
        With Worksheets(1)
            Set foundCell = .Cells.Find(What:=myVar, After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        End With            
        If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then Exit For        
    Next myVar

    If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print foundCell.Address
    End If

End Sub
```

We have two different strings that need to be seaerched for: `"apples*oranges"` and `"oranges*apples"`. The split and the reverse is done pretty primitively:

```
options = Array(str, Split(str, "*")(1) & "*" & Split(str, "*")(0))
```

And then, using a `For Each Loop` with an early `Exit For`, the `.Find()` searches for the two strings.

Comment: This will miss `Oranges*Apples` though

Comment: @Tom - yup, it will.

Comment: @Tom - Unless someone does not decide to put `*` within the initial strings. But hopefully, this is an exceptional case.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple loop alternative:

```
Sub ApplesAndOranges()
    Dim r As Range, fruits As Range
    Set fruits = Nothing
    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        v = r.Value
        If v <> "" Then
            If InStr(v, "apples") <> 0 And InStr(v, "oranges") <> 0 Then
                If fruits Is Nothing Then
                    Set fruits = r
                Else
                    Set fruits = Union(fruits, r)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox fruits.Address(0, 0)
End Sub
```

[image]

From the example, you see it returns **all** cells that contain **both** sub-strings.

Comment: though it will be very slow on large dataset.

Comment: @jainashish  **you are correct!**  I tried to make a regex solution, but the only thing I made was a migraine.